# CSS from style tag not showing up in element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The CSS for the element ".title" is not showing up in the tile element. I am using the C9.io web editor for the cloud. Here is a link to the result.
https://camel-Case-Is-Life-dmitrikonnikov.c9users.io/hello-world.html

```
<head>
<style>
.title{
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;

}

</style>
</head>
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script></head><script>
    /*$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".").addClass("animated bounce");
    });*/
    </script>
    <h1 class="title">Welcome</h1>
```

Comment: You also may want to put the style tag inside the <head> tag, not before.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. It is missing a body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link you provided the markup reads `<h1 id="title">Welcome</h1>` instead of `<h1 class="title">Welcome</h1>`, so the `.title` rule does not apply to it.

[image]

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions however nothing seems to be working.  I suspect a browser cache thing, so i will clear my cache.
</html>

Comment: Then it should work, as seen here: **https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/0r73kosq/2/**

Comment: cleared cache and is still not working. the edited code is in the question above

Comment: Well, don't really know then, probably some issue on c9's part, as I still see that with an `id` instead of a `class` in the [link](https://camel-case-is-life-dmitrikonnikov.c9users.io/hello-world.html) you provided.

Comment: Also, please  do not drastically edit your previous comments, as it breaks the flow of the conversation. My first comment after yours doesn't make sense now because you completely changed your first comment.